# How do I load and save an arrayList<String> into a text class in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, save

I am trying to implement a save and load function in my program that saves an arrayList to a textfile and then can later load all of the past lists I have saved and print them out. I am currently using these two methods:

```
  public static void save(Serializable data, String fileName) throws Exception {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream((Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName))))) {
            oos.writeObject(data);
        }
    }

    public static Object load(String fileName) throws Exception {
        try (ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream((Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName))))) {
            return oos.readObject();
        }
    }
```

As well as a class that represents a list as serializable data.

The problem with this is that it won't save the data after I terminate the program, and when it loads data it prints it with a great deal of extra text besides the list I want it to return. Is there a better or easier way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is covered in the free online tutorial at the oracle web site: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Add a print statement to the save method to see if it's being called. I don't personally rely on Serializeable. If you do, and your structure changes, then you can't read your own files. I always write and read from some sort of standard format, usually JSON. It's more work, but it's safer, IMO.

Comment: Are you flushing and closing your output stream?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a same problem. So I will show you how to do it ...

Be the below `Level` class is what is to be saved:

```java
public class Level implements Serializable {

    private int level = 1;
    private int star;
    private int point;

    // Constructor
    public Level() {

    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setStar(int stars) {
        this.star = stars;
    }

    public int getStar() {
        return star;
    }

    public void setPoint(int points) {
        this.point = points;
    }

    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Level-" + level + "  " + 
        (star > 1 ? star + " stars": star + " star") + "  " +
        (point > 1 ? point + " points" : point + " point") + "\n";
    }

}
```

We will save the list into this file:

```java
    private static final String FILENAME = "data.level";
```

This is the `List` of our objects:

```java
    List<Level> mLevels;
```

Call this method to save the list into the file:

```java
    private void save() {
        if(mLevels.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            oos.writeObject(mLevels);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Use this method to load the list from saved file. Notice, we cast the list of our object with this `(List<Level>) ois.readObject();` in the method:

```java
    private void load() {
        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(mContext.openFileInput(FILENAME));
            mLevels = (List<Level>) ois.readObject();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(mLevels == null) {
            mLevels = new ArrayList<>();
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,"List created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

By now, you should get the idea of how to save your own list.

Comment: 1) Getter, setters are superfluous and are not relevant to the question. Please remove them. 2) save() method is incorrect: You don't save empty list. But an empty list (list of size 0) and no list at all are makes big difference. 3) try/catch is not relevant to this question Please remove that. 4) *you should get the idea* - this is a bad statement. First explain it in words. Then you can show an example. But just showing code without any explanation is a bad answer. Even a question may arise if you understand why you did it in this way.

Comment: @mentallurg Sorry, all your suggestions will make my answer even worse. If you think the save() method is incorrect, compile and see it yourself. try/catch blocks are a MUST for any file/stream operations. Removing them makes the beginners scratch their heads figuring out how to "try and catch" in their code. Thanks.

Comment: When code is used on SO, it should be as brief as possible. 1) Obviously, getters and setter do not help OP to resolve his problem -> they are in your answer *superfluos*. 2) The point is not if it is compileable, but that it is a *logical* error. An example: You have 2 lists, A and B. A has no element. B has some elements. You write A, then B to the same file. The file will contain only 1 list. When you try to read it, how will you know if A was empty and B not empty or vice versa? No way to distinguish. That's why one such approach as an answer here on SO is not helpful.

Comment: ... to try/catch: obviously, the full code must have try/catch. But it is not relevant to the asked question, it does not help to understand the idea --> superfluous --> should be removed. To *scratch their heads* - no, if smb. doesn't understand anything, he just asks it.